# Is there a shortcut for → (U+2192, Rightwards Arrow) in iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard, unicode

When answering questions on Stack Exchange, I like to use → ([U+2192](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2192/index.htm), Rightwards Arrow) to refer to a series of menu options. It's a simple, universally supported character which displays identically on nearly any device. (Example: `Settings → Preferences → Recent Files`)

On a desktop, I can type these quickly using the alt-code shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>. However, I haven't been able to find a similar shortcut on iOS. Usually I resort to copy-pasting the symbol from online.

**Is there a faster way to insert a rightwards arrow → on iOS?**

<sub>**Note**: The desired character → ([U+2192](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2192/index.htm), Rightwards Arrow) is ***not*** the same as ➡ ([U+27A1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27a1/index.htm), Black Rightwards Arrow). The latter renders as [image: iOS arrow] on iOS, and as [image: Windows arrow] on Windows</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a text replacement under **Settings** → **General** → **Keyboard** → **Text Replacement**.

Keep in mind that text replacements work very reliably in iOS, but once they get synced to macOS via iCloud Drive, issues may arise depending on the characters you use in your “shortcuts.”

Refer to [Text replacement problem in Calendar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284580/text-replacement-problem-in-calendar/284831#284831) for more details.